# Xcode 4.2 uninstall crashes Xcode 4.3

Tags: xcode, crash, xcode4.2, upgrade

When XCode 4.3.1 was installed, it asked me if I wanted to remove 4.2. I said no, and proceeded using it. Last night, I decided to uninstall 4.2 with the script included. Now, whenever I run XCode 4.3, it crashes 90% of the time. Has this happened to anyone else, and is there a fix?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This appears to fix the problem

Enter these commands into the Terminal.

```
sudo ln -s /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer /
sudo ln -s /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/OtherFrameworks/DevToolsFoundation.framework /Developer/Library/PrivateFrameworks
```

Quoted from:

http://swipeware.com/xcode-4-3-and-broken-utilities/

Comment: Worked for a couple minutes, and now just back to crashing all the time (95%)

Comment: Well then it sounds like a reinstall might be your best bet, good luck!

Comment: I've reinstalled 6 times since the crashes started happening to no avail. Even a fresh reinstall just crashes (fresh pertaining to Xcode)

Comment: I tried deleting caches and made my problem worse because somehow, my Applications folder Contents was removed as well.

Comment: Try uninstalling 4.3 then installing 4.2 then installing 4.3 over it like the first time except hit yes this time when it asks to to remove 4.2

Answer (score 1):

When uninstalling xcode 4.3.1 try removing the preferences from xcode in **~/Library/Preferences/** too. It sometimes help me with other applications.

Comment: How did you manage to remove xcode 4.3.1 anyways in the first place?

Comment: Not 4.3.1, 4.2.1. As for removing XCode 4.3.1, I used AppCleaner + 4.3.1, and reinstalled 4.2.1

Comment: Hi Antek, sorry for my late answer. Like i said, it helped me with other applications. Maybe you could have a look at the AppCleaner mentioned by Jon.